# Error: Activity resulted into multiple skype activities bot FrameWork

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to send an attachment using proactive messaging to a channel,
below is my code.

```
async function sendToChannelWithImage(message,channelId,img) {
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl('');

    var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials('app-id', 'password');
    var client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/us/' });

    var conversationResponse = await client.conversations.createConversation({
        bot: {
            id: 'app-id',
            name: 'test'
        },
        isGroup: true,
        conversationType: "channel",
        channelData: {
            channel: { id: channelId }
        },
        activity: {
            type: 'message',
            text: message,
            attachments: [img]
        }
    });
}
```

```
const img = {contentType: 'image/*',contentUrl: "https://theysaidso.com/img/qod/qod-inspire.jpg"};
message = 'test'
channelId = 'testid'
```

In this I am getting trying to send the message using bot framework,
what i have tried : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-receive-attachments

Comment: Are you trying to send an attachment to a channel or create a conversation?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes

Comment: I am trying to send an attachment to channel

Comment: You have neither upvoted nor accepted my answer, and you decided to let your bounty expire rather than award it to me. Still I am willing to help you. Do you still need help?

Comment: sorry @KyleDelaney but I didn't get my answer, but now I have migrated to a different platform, but I appreciate your attempt, one upvote for that :-)

Comment: Are you saying you're no longer working on this?

Comment: yep, We have moved to another vendor.

Comment: Well then you might want to consider accepting an answer so this doesn't look like an open question. If you don't want to accept mine then you can post your own saying the actions you've taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a proactive message to a Teams team channel is no different from sending a proactive message to a personal conversation, so you should be using `sendToConversation` instead of `createConversation`. To send a proactive message anywhere, you'll need to make sure you have the conversation ID. In Teams, it's also important to [trust the service URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages).

If you want to start a new thread in a team channel, you can do that by removing the thread ID from the conversation ID. See here: [Microsoft Bot - Node SDK: How to post to a public channel *without replying to a prev. activity*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080986/microsoft-bot-node-sdk-how-to-post-to-a-public-channel-without-replying-to-a/62094396#62094396)

It looks like there's a sample about starting new threads in team channels if you'd like to check that out: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel

Comment: I'll try this and let you know about it, btw thanx for the help :-)

Comment: I just tried this but I don't think this is the answer to my question, as I am trying to send the messages using the channel ID,  not by the conversation ID, as I have to save conversations in that case, which I don't want, as I already know that channel Ids are statics and don't change too often, so can you please help me in that direction

Comment: Teams is your channel. The "channel ID" as understood by the Bot Framework is `msteams`. Unfortunately, Teams has its own things called teams and channels, so the terms are ambiguous. I'm guessing when you say "channel ID" you mean the ID of the Teams team channel and not the ID of the Bot Framework channel. In that case, there's no difference between that and the conversation ID. All threads in a team channel share a root conversation ID that can be used to identify the team channel. Can you explain why you think the conversation ID isn't static, and is different from the channel ID?